# How to read an integers on text file in c#

Tags: c#, file, text

I'm beginner in c#, so i have a question.I have a text file that contains integers separated with commas, like this;

> 1,1.0,2.0,1.0,2,3.0,23.0,15.0,1.0

And in this file there are about 2000(maybe more) integers.I want to read this integers on text file by one by and write a list.

How can i do this?

Thanks...

So thanks to your helps i tried this ;

```
 public List<double> getlist()
    {
        List<double> valuesList = new List<double>();

        string pat;

        getfilelocation b = new getfilelocation();

        pat = b.getPath();

        System.IO.StreamReader rdr = System.IO.File.OpenText(pat);
        string values = rdr.ReadToEnd();
        rdr.Close();
        string[] vls = values.Split(',');

        foreach (string value in vls)
        {
            double d;
            if (double.TryParse(value, out d))
            {
                valuesList.Add(d);
            }

        }

        return valuesList;
    }
```

Is this true?

Comment: Why do you have ".0" on several entries if they're all meant to be integers? How would you want "1.5" to be handled? Are the values all on the same line in the file? I assume you meant "one by one" instead of "by one by" - any reason for this?

Comment: You can start by attempting to write code. Then when you encounter problems, create a question and explain exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: I researched this, but all answers are different one guy use TextReader , other guy use FileStream etc...

Comment: @OnurEryilmaz try it both ways how you know what you like if don't try them both?

Comment: Use TextReader or StreamReader, Read line by lines and split each line with comma as delimiter. Start with sample code and post your issues.

Comment: sorry i mean by one by, .0 's only an example, "1.5,1.6,23.4..." are include in this file...And yes all of this integers are in same line...

Comment: Nobody will write this for you until you try and write it yourself first.

Comment: Maybe someone needs to repeat this to you, 1.5, 1.6, 23.4 are NOT integers. @Jasti just gave you almost the complete solution, you just need to translate that to C#.

Comment: Wht get down vote?Please think about question.this question is not bad.

Comment: @Onur, Thank you for posting code.  Does the code do what you want it to do?  If it doesn't, what's the problem with it?  Please ask specific questions.

Comment: @Wayne , Yes it does but i have still one problem.I get the path on user in my getPath() method,and i check this method and its work properly bu in this case ;
System.IO.StreamReader rdr = System.IO.File.OpenText(pat);
The compiler does not see any error but when i debug it the program doesn't accept value "pat".

Bu instead of this problem(which is irrelevant for my main question) my problem has solved, thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's many ways.  Here's one rudimentary way:

Read the complete contents into a string.

```
System.IO.StreamReader rdr = System.IO.File.OpenText("c:\\myfile.txt")
string stringvalues = rdr.ReadToEnd();
rdr.Close();
```

Then split the values by commas:

```
string[] stringvalues = csvintegers.split(',');
```

Then convert them into doubles (you say integers, but I see decimials, so I'll suggest you use doubles).

```
List<double> doublevalues = new List<double>();
foreach(string value in stringvalues)
{
    doublevalues.Add(double.Parse(value));
}
```

Now you have a list of values...

Answer (score 0):

Since you're a beginner, here is some help:

```
        var file = File.ReadAllText("yourPath");
        var list = new List<double>();
        foreach (var s in file.Split(','))
        {
            double d;
            if (double.TryParse(s, out d))
                list.Add(d);
        }
```